# How to group multiple instances of each application in taskbar/panel?

Tags: windows, cinnamon, taskbar, groups, multiple-instances

I am looking for a solution that can provide me "Windows"-like capability to [group multiple instances](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visio/2009/12/18/visio-2010-better-with-windows-7/) of each application in ubuntu.

I have looked at the solution to this question at some other questions that showed up on search, but those solutions seem to be outdated (from 2011, 2012...) in a sense that the suggested "applets" are no longer supported or updated for the recent/latest versions of ubuntu. I have `Linux (4.8.0-53-generic) Cinnamon 3.4.6 64-bit`.

Comment: Depends on the DE. Mint is not supported here, try Mint forum or Unix & Linux. In case of Ubuntu you'll have to mention which DE (Unity/GNOME/KDE/MATE/XFCE/LXDE/Budgie etc.) you're using.

Comment: I am using Cinnamon as DE.

Comment: Then update your question accordingly with the correct cinnamon version.

Comment: @pomsky: I've updated the question with the requested information. Thanks.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?